# How to add a footer icon with JS in MediaWiki

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

So I want to put a footer icon in my MediaWiki (note that I'm using Miraheze) with JS because I can't use `$wgFooterIcons` because Miraheze doesn't have that option in ManageWiki

So, give any code that adds a Footer icon pls

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try below and let me know if i understood your question correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var footerIcon = document.createElement('div');
    footerIcon.id = 'customFooterIcon';
    footerIcon.innerHTML = '<a href="ICONLINK" title="Your Icon Title"><img src="ICONLINK" alt=""></a>';
 
    $('#footer-places').append(footerIcon);
});
```